# How to use my public IP?

Tags: networking

I want to set up my PC with public IP settings. I tried to set it by adding it in 'Edit Connections' as I do with the Win PCs in my office. But http://www.whatismyip.com/ reports the IP of my proxy.

Googling doesnt help much, as 11.10 results are hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're connecting to Internet via a proxy (ADSL modem being kind of a proxy too), then it's a matter of configuring the proxy to forward traffic from internet to and from the machine in the local network. Usually there's nothing you need to do on the machine itself.

The keywords to google for are NAT and port forwarding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is, to reach your PC from the internet (and I don't know another reason why you want to use your public IP), you can setup a [DMZ.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29)